# How to grep with input ansi color encoding maintained?

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, ansi-escape, ansi-colors

The following `grep` does not maintain the input ANSI color encoding. Is there a way to maintain the original color encoding?

```
$ builtin printf '%s\n' $'\e[33mx\e[0m' | grep $'\e\[33m' 
x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable `grep`'s coloring with `--color=never`:

```
$ builtin printf '%s\n' $'\e[33mx\e[0m' | grep --color=never $'\e\[33m'
```

Otherwise, `grep` inserts an escape sequence before the searched string `\e\[33m` to color it, and then after inserts another sequence to reset all colorings, which in turn causes the letter x to be not colored on the output.

The default coloring mode of `grep` is `--color=auto`, which colors the output only if the output is a terminal. So, another way of disabling the coloring would be redirecting the output of `grep` to somewhere other than the terminal, e.g. `cat`:

```
$ builtin printf '%s\n' $'\e[33mx\e[0m' | grep $'\e\[33m' | cat
```

Comment: I suggest to add to the explanation that `grep` does the coloring by default only when the output is a terminal. (If you add another pipe, e.g. `builtin printf '%s\n' $'\e[33mx\e[0m' | grep $'\e\[33m'|cat` the output will also show the expected color.)